# Finding a monic quadratic polynomial which is a factor of two other polynomials

Tags: polynomials, factoring

### Problem statement:

Find a monic quadratic polynomial, $f(x)$, which divides both $$g(x) = 12x^3 − 30x^2 + 18x − 12$$ and $$h(x) = 6x^4 + 3x^3 + 6x^2 + 3$$

### My take on it:

I divided $h(x)$ by $g(x)$ to get the quotient and remainder such that $$6x^4 + 3x^3 + 6x^2 + 3 = (12x^3 − 30x^2 + 18x − 12)(\frac{1}{2}x + \frac{3}{2}) + 3(14x^2 - 11x + 7)$$

It is also the case that any polynomial divisor of both $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ must also divide the remainder polynomial when $h(x)$ is divided by $g(x)$.

So following on from that, our common factor for $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ that we're trying to find, would also have to be a factor of our remainder, $3(14x^2 - 11x + 7)$. Yet the remainder cannot be factorised any further to turn it into a monic quadratic polynomial.

*How should I go about solving this problem?*

So far, it's only this particular problem that I find myself unable to solve, other ones like it are fine.

**Important:** Please don't provide the full solution but rather only the way forward as I don't want to be accused of plagiarism. This exact problem is part of an assignment.

---

**EDIT:** I actually had an error in my calculation, the resulting equation is now as follows
$$
6x^4 + 3x^3 + 6x^2 + 3 = (12x^3 − 30x^2 + 18x − 12)(\frac{1}{2}x + \frac{3}{2}) + 42(x^2 - \frac{1}{2}x + \frac{1}{2})
$$

Comment: I think you made an error in your computations as [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(12x%5E3-30x%5E2%2B18x-12)(x-3)%2F2-6x%5E4%2B3x%5E3%2B6x%5E2%2B3) shows the remainder to be $3(10x^3-20x^2+11x-7)$.   Your approach is a good one.  Now find a linear combination of $h(x)$ and the remainder that removes the cubic term and you should be left with a multiple of the desired quadratic.

Comment: @RossMillikan Thanks! I actually had a typo in my question (- instead of +). But I also had a calculation error as you suggested. Now I get $42(x^2 - \frac{1}{2}x + \frac{1}{2}$, which is basically what the other answer suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we have:
$$
12x^3-30x^2+18x-12=6(2x^3-5x^2+3x-2)
$$

and we see that $x=2$ is a root, so, dividing by $(x-2)$ we find:
$$
12x^3-30x^2+18x-12=6(x-2)(2x^2-x+1)
$$

Now show that $2x^2-x+1$ divides the other polynomial. And you can write it as a monic polynomial  using:
$$
2\left(x^2-\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{1}{2} \right)
$$

Comment: The required polynomial must be monic, though.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs : added to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

=-=-=-=-==-

$$  \left(  6 x^{4}  + 3 x^{3}  + 6 x^{2}  + 3 \right)  $$

$$  \left(  12 x^{3}  - 30 x^{2}  + 18 x  - 12 \right)  $$

$$  \left(  6 x^{4}  + 3 x^{3}  + 6 x^{2}  + 3 \right)  =  \left(  12 x^{3}  - 30 x^{2}  + 18 x  - 12 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  x  + 3 }{ 2 }  \right) } +  \left(  42 x^{2}  - 21 x  + 21 \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(  12 x^{3}  - 30 x^{2}  + 18 x  - 12 \right)  =  \left(  42 x^{2}  - 21 x  + 21 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{ 2 x  - 4 }{ 7 }  \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 0}{1} $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 1}{0} $$ 
 $$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  x  + 3 }{ 2 }  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   \frac{  x  + 3 }{ 2 }  \right) }{ \left( 1  \right) } $$ 
 $$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{ 2 x  - 4 }{ 7 }  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   \frac{  x^{2}  +  x  + 1 }{ 7 }  \right) }{ \left(   \frac{ 2 x  - 4 }{ 7 }  \right) } $$ 
 $$  \left(   x^{2}  +  x  + 1 \right)  \left( \frac{ 1}{7 } \right)  -  \left(   x  - 2 \right)  \left(   \frac{  x  + 3 }{ 7 }  \right)  =  \left( 1  \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(  6 x^{4}  + 3 x^{3}  + 6 x^{2}  + 3 \right)  =  \left(   x^{2}  +  x  + 1 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(  6 x^{2}  - 3 x  + 3 \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(  12 x^{3}  - 30 x^{2}  + 18 x  - 12 \right)  =  \left(   x  - 2 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(  6 x^{2}  - 3 x  + 3 \right) } +  \left(  6 x^{3}  - 15 x^{2}  + 9 x  - 6 \right)  $$ 
 $$  \mbox{GCD} =   \color{magenta}{  \left(  6 x^{2}  - 3 x  + 3 \right) }   $$ 
 $$  \left(  6 x^{4}  + 3 x^{3}  + 6 x^{2}  + 3 \right)  \left( \frac{ 1}{7 } \right)  -  \left(  6 x^{3}  - 15 x^{2}  + 9 x  - 6 \right)  \left(   \frac{  x  + 3 }{ 7 }  \right)  =  \left(  6 x^{2}  - 3 x  + 3 \right)  $$